# Words to describe the person who made the complaint and the one who is being complained

Tags: nouns

I am looking for nouns for

1. A person who made a complaint;
2. The person who is being complained about.

I would have used "complainer" but that sounds wrong as it is closer to saying that person likes to complain a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A person who made a complaint is a *complainant*

A person who is being complained about is a *complainee*

Edit :

I've had a good look on the internet and can't find a definition of *complainee* other than those used in contracts for housing associations (worldwide) and similar not strictly legal enforcement entities, however the word is used very widely in the meaning of *the person who is complained about* in all manner of places, legal and otherwise include the UK Police Guide and the US Attorney General website.

It's used but not defined in a couple of legal dictionaries and the only place that I've found a definition for it is the OED1 which defines is as

> (kɒmˌpleɪˈniː) [f. complain v. + -ee, the suffix not being here
>   etymological.] **The person complained against**.

It's not marked as 'rare' or 'obsolete'. One reference in one dictionary usually doesn't stand a word in good stead but as it's the OED I imagine that gives it some weight. Why it's not defined on other dictionaries is a mystery.

It's also worth nothing that on my scour of the internet I found an awful lot of people using it to mean *the complainant* as in *there were a lot of us complainees talking to the manager* so if you need to then you should make it clear what you mean.

Comment: +1 for complainant, but I can not google complainee from common results

Comment: @user1589188 Terms that are based in the law and found in a legal dictionary

Comment: I'm surprised that _complainee_ isn't readily accessible online, it's a common enough term that isn't burdened with the gravity of _defendant_. Normally a _defendant_ would be in a court of law, a _complainee_ would more likely be found in a private hearing.

Comment: Used in fewer circumstances, but also valid for the one being complained about is _respondent_.

Answer (score 3):

"Respondent" can be used to describe a person against whom a complaint is made.

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me--the person being complained about might be a respondent, but they might not be. Also, you don't answer the whole question.

Comment: +1 This is indeed the standard term for the party opposed to the _complainant_ in some legal proceedings.

Comment: For example in MIT disciplinary cases: http://studentlife.mit.edu/faqs/what-do-terms-complainant-respondent-witness-and-advisor-words-mean-disciplinary-case-referral-form

Answer (score 2):

A word for complainer is :

> **[Querulist](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/272656/querulist)** : complainer

&

accused, defendant, or suspect for the person who is being complained about.

Answer (score 2):

Grievant is another good word for the complainer, as in the person who filed the grievance.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) traces _grievant_ (which it defines as "one who submits a grievance for arbitration") to 1958, and the word's [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grievant&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrievant%3B%2Cc0) indicates that it remains fairly rare. Even rarer, though, is _grievee_, which is occasionally used to indicate the party against whom the grievant's grievance is directed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***plaintiff/defendant***

> plaintiff
>
> *n.* the party who initiates a lawsuit by filing a complaint with the clerk of the court against the **defendant**(s) demanding damages, performance and/or court determination of rights. [Gerald N. Hill and Kathleen T. Hill](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/plaintiff)

Comment: It's a little law-related.